# android - alert dialog that user can't pass without click on the button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I'm trying to build an alert dialog that shows terms of use for my app.
I added 2 buttons: one button is "accept" and the other "decline" .

the problem is: the user can simply click on the screen that outside from the dialog, and pass the dialog without accepting the terms of use.
can I prevent it?

sorry for bad english

this is my code:

```
       AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("הבהרה");
      dialog.setMessage("המידע באפליקציה זו מובא כמו שהוא, אחריות השימוש בו חלה על הקורא בלבד. האפליקציה לא מהווה תחליף ליעוץ רפואי או/ו יעוץ מקצועי. מטרת התכנים באפליקציה היא סיפוק מידע כללי ואינה המלצה או/ו הצעה רפואית. לקורא לא תהיה שום תביעה או תלונה כלפי המפתחים. ");


       dialog.setPositiveButton("מסכים",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                  dialog.cancel();
              }


          });
       dialog.setNegativeButton("לא מסכים",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                Intent intent5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Splash.class);
                startActivity(intent5);
               dialog.cancel();
           }


       });
       AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
       alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: dialog.setCancelable(false);

Answer (score 0):

Make your dialog non cancelable by calling `dialog.setCancelabel(false);`.

For other such method details, kindly refer to the official documentation for [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html).